# Preload a view in laravel with different data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sentinel

I am using Laravel and sentinel to develop a permission system however it was designed so that the user can select and deselect which permissions the role has from a checkbox form. I have already coded the part where they can assign permissions however I need that the checkboxes that have already been assigned are marked when the user request the page. How do you recommend approaching this? I am using a middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel;

class PermissionsMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Sentinel::findById(1);
        $permisos = array(array_keys($user['permissions']))

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

However, I don't know how to pass data from the middleware to the view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's recommended using the middleware for this purpose, but if you still want to do it that way you can try using:

```
View::share ( 'permisos', $permisos );
```

To share the 'permisos' variable with the view that's coming after the middleware.

So your code is going to look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel;

class PermissionsMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Sentinel::findById(1);
        $permisos = array(array_keys($user['permissions']))
        View::share ( 'permisos', $permisos );

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: it returns  App\Http\Middleware\View but what would you use?

Comment: Do you mean what class you have use?

Comment: No I mean how would you get the data in the view itself?

Comment: Just use $permisos